# How to integrate intercom with thinkific

Tags: javascript, intercom

I would like to connect thinkific with intercom, using the following code from within the template:

```
    <head>
          <script>
           if({{site.current_user.signed_in}}) {
             window.intercomSettings = {
              app_id: "xxxxx",
              name: "{{ site.current_user.full_name }}", 
              //email: "test@test.com", // They dont provide this variable {{ site.current_user.email}}
             };
         } else {
              window.intercomSettings = {
               app_id: "xxxxx",
             };
        }
        </script>
        <script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/edetfbym';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
  </head>
```

It works good for the Leads, but the only problem I am facing is when the user is logged in and I cant get his email address or user id of thinkific that I can pass into the intercom object... This way it would have worked perfectly fine the integration.

I have been looking at these available variables from the thinkific documentation: http://help.thinkific.com/support/solutions/articles/216707-variables-version-1-x-x , but seems like they don't provide user email as a variable to access from within the template.

Any idea, how else I would integrate intercom into thinkific?

Answer (score 0):

it worked by changing to this:

```
window.intercomSettings = {
         app_id: "edetfbym",
         name: "{{ site.current_user.full_name }}", // Full name
         email: Thinkific.current_user.email, // Email address
       };
```

Hopefully this have helped someone else having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to replace the 2 app id's & ensure identity verification is disabled in intercom, otherwise it won't work once users log in.

```
<script>
      if(Thinkific.current_user !== null) {
      window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: "APP_ID",
        name: Thinkific.current_user.full_name, // Full name
        email: Thinkific.current_user.email // Email address
         };
      } else {
                window.intercomSettings = {
                app_id: "APP_ID",
                };
            }
    </script>
    <script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/erckqe4k';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
```